# Cant connect to azure service bus topic using java

Tags: java, azure, azureservicebus

I am trying to connect to Azure service bus topic using java code. 
I have created a topic in azure portal .

I am trying to configure using the method configureWithWrapAuthentication which has the parameters namespace,authenticationName,authenticationPassword,serviceBusRootUri,**wrapRootUri** .

I obtained all the parameter values except wrapRootUri .
FYI : I have selected the region as **South India**

I need to know what is the value of wrapRootUri for South India location .

Please help!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The service bus team on the change from ACS to SAS. It seems that it no longer works. According to github there is an [open issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues/437).

If you want to connect or manage Azure service bus. I recommand that you could use the following [SDK](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/azure-servicebus/2.0.0-PREVIEW-5).

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/azure-servicebus -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-servicebus</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-PREVIEW-5</version>
</dependency>
```

**Update**: add package information.

Demo code

```
import com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.ClientSettings;
import com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.Message;
import com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.TopicClient;
import com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.management.ManagementClient;
import com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.management.TopicDescription;
import com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.primitives.ConnectionStringBuilder;
import com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.security.SharedAccessSignatureTokenProvider;
import com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.security.TokenProvider;


 String connectionString = "Endpoint=sb://yoursevicebusNamespace.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=xxxxx";
 ConnectionStringBuilder connectionStringBuilder = new ConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);
 ManagementClient client = new ManagementClient(connectionStringBuilder);
 //create topic
 if(!client.queueExists("topicName")) 
 {
    TopicDescription topic = client.createTopic("topicName");

 }

 TokenProvider tokenProvider = new SharedAccessSignatureTokenProvider("RootManageSharedAccessKey","xxxxxx",30);
 ClientSettings clientSettings = new ClientSettings(tokenProvider){};
 //create topicClient
 TopicClient topicClient = new TopicClient(connectionStringBuilder.getEndpoint(),"topicName",clientSettings);
 //send message
 topicClient.send(new Message("test message"));
```

Comment: Can u send me the import of ManagementClient and TopicDescription

Comment: @MithunManohar I have updated the answer with importing package information.

Comment: Can u please add the code to receive the message as well

Comment: @MithunManohar If you have any other question, I recommend that you could  post another SO thread. If it is useful, you could mark it as an answer.

Comment: `TokenProvider tokenProvider = new SharedAccessSignatureTokenProvider("RootManageSharedAccessKey","xxxx",30);
ClientSettings clientSettings = new ClientSettings(tokenProvider){};
IMessageReceiver receiver = ClientFactory.createMessageReceiverFromEntityPath("servicebusNamespace","topicName",clientSettings);
receiver.receive();`

Comment: If there a more than one message in the queue then how till we receive it

Comment: You could refer to [SDK document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.servicebus._i_message_receiver.receive?view=azure-java-stable#com_microsoft_azure_servicebus__i_message_receiver_receive__) to learn how to use the method.`receiver.receiveBatch(number)`